# mongoDBのパスの通し方を教えてください

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

#### 質問内容

以下のエラーの解決方法を教えてください。

```
Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

#### 現状

以前mongoDBを起動したときは使えたのだが強制終了してしまったせいか、再度起動できなくなってしまいました。

```
$ sudo service mongod start
mongod: unrecognized service
```

```
$ mongod
2020-09-17T18:10:14.072+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=134 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=LAPTOP-LSE3HD1V
2020-09-17T18:10:14.078+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.24
2020-09-17T18:10:14.085+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 865b4f6a96d0f5425e39a18337105f33e8db504d
2020-09-17T18:10:14.086+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2020-09-17T18:10:14.087+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-09-17T18:10:14.092+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-09-17T18:10:14.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-09-17T18:10:14.101+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2020-09-17T18:10:14.102+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-09-17T18:10:14.107+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-09-17T18:10:14.108+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-09-17T18:10:14.120+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2020-09-17T18:10:14.121+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-09-17T18:10:14.127+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2020-09-17T18:10:14.129+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-09-17T18:10:14.135+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

ここで

```
2020-09-17T18:10:14.120+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

より、dbというディレクトリがないことがわかりました。一応見てみると、

```
/data$ ls
db
/data$ cd db
-bash: cd: db: No such file or directory
```

となっていました。
このコードの2行目に「db」とある気がするのですが、とりあえず起動できません。

ディレクトリを作れということなのかと思い、同じ階層に「db1」というものを作りました。

```
/data$ mkdir db1
/data$ ls
db  db1
```

その後、

```
$ mongod -dbpath /data/db1
2020-09-17T18:09:20.877+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=126 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db1 64-bit host=LAPTOP-LSE3HD1V
2020-09-17T18:09:20.882+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.24
2020-09-17T18:09:20.883+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 865b4f6a96d0f5425e39a18337105f33e8db504d
2020-09-17T18:09:20.890+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2020-09-17T18:09:20.891+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-09-17T18:09:20.892+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-09-17T18:09:20.897+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-09-17T18:09:20.902+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2020-09-17T18:09:20.903+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-09-17T18:09:20.904+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-09-17T18:09:20.905+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/data/db1" } }
2020-09-17T18:09:20.969+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7569M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2020-09-17T18:09:21.035+0900 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (22) [1600333761:35092][126:0x7fe7bed81180], connection: /data/db1/: directory-sync: fdatasync: Invalid argument
2020-09-17T18:09:21.038+0900 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1600333761:38949][126:0x7fe7bed81180], connection: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2020-09-17T18:09:21.046+0900 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28558 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 365
2020-09-17T18:09:21.052+0900 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure


2020-09-17T18:09:21.113+0900 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x7fe7c03610b1 0x7fe7c03602c9 0x7fe7c03607ad 0x7fe7bd7528a0 0x7fe7bd37ef47 0x7fe7bd3808b1 0x7fe7bf5f39f1 0x7fe7c0068f86 0x7fe7bf5fe0a8 0x7fe7bf5fe2cd 0x7fe7bf5fe52f 0x7fe7c0d17857 0x7fe7c0d179f2 0x7fe7c0d1837b 0x7fe7c0d14581 0x7fe7c0c72b06 0x7fe7c0d3489f 0x7fe7c0d1242b 0x7fe7c0cc109a 0x7fe7c004d3af 0x7fe7c0045aa2 0x7fe7bff386e0 0x7fe7bf5deaf3 0x7fe7bf5ff926 0x7fe7bd361b97 0x7fe7bf660379
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"15B30B1","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"15B22C9"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"15B27AD"},{"b":"7FE7BD740000","o":"128A0"},{"b":"7FE7BD340000","o":"3EF47","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7FE7BD340000","o":"408B1","s":"abort"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"8459F1","s":"_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"12BAF86"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"8500A8","s":"__wt_eventv"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"8502CD","s":"__wt_err"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"85052F","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1F69857"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1F699F2"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1F6A37B"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1F66581","s":"__wt_open"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1EC4B06","s":"__wt_block_manager_create"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1F8689F","s":"__wt_schema_create"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1F6442B","s":"__wt_turtle_init"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1F1309A","s":"wiredtiger_open"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"129F3AF","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mbbbb"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"1297AA2"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"118A6E0","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"830AF3"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"851926","s":"main"},{"b":"7FE7BD340000","o":"21B97","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"7FE7BEDAE000","o":"8B2379","s":"_start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.4.24", "gitVersion" : "865b4f6a96d0f5425e39a18337105f33e8db504d", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-18362-Microsoft", "version" : "#1049-Microsoft Thu Aug 14 12:01:00 PST 2020", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "7FE7BEDAE000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2D1022085B581BB8C5C09845FF38D62AB6F14607" }, { "b" : "7FFFE394D000", "path" : "linux-vdso.so.1", "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7FE7BE790000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0D054641049B9747C05D030262295DFDFDD3055D" }, { "b" : "7FE7BE340000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9C228817BA6E0730F4FCCFAC6E033BD1E0C5620A" }, { "b" : "7FE7BE130000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3F29B196C7C124797473113FD2D0833881BF0DE5" }, { "b" : "7FE7BDF20000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B22BAF34FB22284EC8E3818961CDF01CCAB3441C" }, { "b" : "7FE7BDB80000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9EF1967ED985A60AC2288C3E1D8C8375F48B841D" }, { "b" : "7FE7BD960000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "679F3AE11120EC7C483BC9295345D836F5C104F7" }, { "b" : "7FE7BD740000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BC3C06107774266C5F7DB3F1F380A3DA68AF90FA" }, { "b" : "7FE7BD340000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D3CF764B2F97AC3EFE366DDD07AD902FB6928FD7" }, { "b" : "7FE7BEA00000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C93445FE9506EEE727E6F04F1AC8F460E49EB366" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x7fe7c03610b1]
 mongod(+0x15B22C9) [0x7fe7c03602c9]
 mongod(+0x15B27AD) [0x7fe7c03607ad]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x128A0) [0x7fe7bd7528a0]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0xC7) [0x7fe7bd37ef47]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7fe7bd3808b1]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj+0x0) [0x7fe7bf5f39f1]
 mongod(+0x12BAF86) [0x7fe7c0068f86]
 mongod(__wt_eventv+0x3D7) [0x7fe7bf5fe0a8]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x9D) [0x7fe7bf5fe2cd]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x2E) [0x7fe7bf5fe52f]
 mongod(+0x1F69857) [0x7fe7c0d17857]
 mongod(+0x1F699F2) [0x7fe7c0d179f2]
 mongod(+0x1F6A37B) [0x7fe7c0d1837b]
 mongod(__wt_open+0x491) [0x7fe7c0d14581]
 mongod(__wt_block_manager_create+0x66) [0x7fe7c0c72b06]
 mongod(__wt_schema_create+0x4EF) [0x7fe7c0d3489f]
 mongod(__wt_turtle_init+0x36B) [0x7fe7c0d1242b]
 mongod(wiredtiger_open+0x194A) [0x7fe7c0cc109a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mbbbb+0x70F) [0x7fe7c004d3af]
 mongod(+0x1297AA2) [0x7fe7c0045aa2]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x6B0) [0x7fe7bff386e0]
 mongod(+0x830AF3) [0x7fe7bf5deaf3]
 mongod(main+0x966) [0x7fe7bf5ff926]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xE7) [0x7fe7bd361b97]
 mongod(_start+0x29) [0x7fe7bf660379]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
Aborted (core dumped)
```

と表示されました。

ここまでやってもmongodbは起動できませんでした。
どういう直し方をすればよいのかわからないので、投稿させていただきました。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating で検索したところ色々解決策が出てきました。https://qiita.com/FumiyaShibusawa/items/cb224d3658be8acf4b8e こちらお試しになられましたでしょうか。Macとは違いますので設定ファイルの場所は違うかもしれませんがエラーは同じですから参考になるかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

エラーログのうち、

```
"uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-18362-Microsoft", "version" : "#1049-Microsoft Thu Aug 14 12:01:00 PST 2020", "machine" : "x86_64" }
```

の部分からすると、WSL: Windows Sybsystem for Linuxを使っていると思います。

しかしMongoDBは公式にはWSLをサポートしていません。マニュアルの[Supported Platforms](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#supported-platforms)に記載がありません。クラッシュしているのはこのためだと思われます。

まずは普通のLinux環境でやり直すか、もしくはWindowsを使うのであればWindows版のMongoDBをインストールしてみてください。